# Vim filter command for one word

Tags: vim, filter

Is it possible to run vim filter command(:!) for only one word. Not on whole line as default? Or maybe is it possible to run something like: command (word from file)?

Comment: Are you filtering (`:<range>!`) or just running a command (`:!`), and do you want to pass the word as a command argument, or as standard input? Does the command have output, and where do you want the output to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the `system()` function.

Test in Windows

#### before:

```
date /t
```

#### run command:

```
:s@date /t@\=system(submatch(0))@
```

#### after:

```
Sun 02/19/2012
```